# gridview row update only when changed, javascript not changing value :(

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, hidden-field

I've got a gridview (ASP.net) inside of an update panel.  I also have a "Save" button
so that when I click "Save" it loops through all the rows of a grid view and passes the data to a stored procedure to update each row.  This was too slow as sometimes I would be updating the database even though a change did not occur.

I decided to add a field in my gridview like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <input type="hidden" id="hdnIsChanged" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

That is, I added a hidden field and the idea was that if a textbox or drop down value changed in my gridview row I would update this hidden field with the value 1.  So I added this to my `gvLineItems_RowDataBound` event:

```
Dim hiddenField As HtmlInputHidden = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("hdnIsChanged"), HtmlInputHidden)

    'the line item date
    Dim tLID As TextBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("txtLineItemDate"), TextBox)
    tLID.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenField.ClientID + "').value=1")

    'the amount field
    Dim ta As TextBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("txtAmount"), TextBox)
    ta.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenField.ClientID + "').value=1")
```

The idea was so that onchange it would set the value 1.  Then in my save button I'd do something to this effect:

```
  For Each Row As GridViewRow In Me.gvLineItems.Rows

            Dim hiddenField As HtmlInputHidden = DirectCast(Row.FindControl("hdnIsChanged"), HtmlInputHidden)

            If (hiddenField.Value = "1") Then
              'perform the update...
```

The issue I am having is when I debug I see that `hiddenField.Value` is always 1 whether I change a value in the textbox or not. I found this similiar post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1592125.aspx/1

It seems to work for that guy, but for me the value is always 1...

Comment: Any javascript errors or other debug info?

Comment: @Dave - How do I display JS errors in IE9.  In IE8 they used to be in the status bar...

Comment: I don't use IE9 yet.  Maybe hit f12 and see if it brings up developer tools?

Comment: @Dave - see update above in my initial post...

Comment: @Anyone - Please anyone have any idea why the `hiddenfield` value is always `1` even if I don't change the value of my textbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its now working all of a sudden, it seems to fail for any textbox that is associated with a calendarextender (ajax).  So I got rid of the rowdatabound for this one field and it works now...strange.

Answer (score 1):

getElementById, lowercase the last D.

Comment: This is definately one part of the fix, but the issue is the value for the hidden field is always 1.  No matter if I make a change to the field or not :(...